# How to generate tls certificate and keys with fabric-ca

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am able to register & enroll `peer/orderer` identity with `fabric-ca`. Now I want to generate tls certs and key for that. Does anyone know how to do that?

Any reference/steps would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-m` and `--enrollment.profile` flags with the fabric-ca-client ( https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clientcli.html ).

`fabric-ca-client enroll -m $HOSTNAME --enrollment.profile tls ...`

$HOSTNAME is host to use (e.g. peer0.org1.example.com, localhost, peer0).  If you need to supply multiple SANS, you can use the `--csr.hosts` option which takes a comma-separated list.  Fabric CA has a built-in `tls` profile which issues X509 certs with the proper extended key usages.